# Can take be used in a query expression in c# linq instead of using .Take(x)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write some LINQ To SQL code that would generate SQL like

```
SELECT t.Name, g.Name
FROM Theme t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [Group] ORDER BY TotalMembers
) as g ON t.K = g.ThemeK
```

So far I have

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes 
join g in dc.Groups on t.K equals g.ThemeK into groups 
select new { 
    t.Name, Groups = (from z in groups orderby z.TotalMembers select z.Name )
};
```

but I need to do a top/take on the ordered groups subquery. According to http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/01/08/converting-sql-to-linq-part-7-union-top-subqueries-bill-horst.aspx in VB I could just add TAKE 5 on the end, but I can't get this syntax to work in c#. How do you use the take syntax in c#?

edit: PS adding .Take(5) at the end causes it to run loads of individual queries

edit 2: I made a slight mistake with the intent of the SQL above, but the question still stands. **The problem is that if you use extension methods in the query like .Take(5), LinqToSql runs lots of SQL queries instead of a single query.**

Comment: Its a better practice to update/edit your question and/or add comments to answers when responding to questions.  That way you won't have a buttload of bogus answers in your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a faithful translation of the original query.  This should not generate repeated roundtrips.

```
var subquery =
  dc.Groups
  .OrderBy(g => g.TotalMembers)
  .Take(5);

var query =
  dc.Themes
  .Join(subquery, t => t.K, g => g.ThemeK, (t, g) => new
  {
    ThemeName = t.Name, GroupName = g.Name
  }
  );
```

The roundtrips in the question are caused by the groupjoin (join into).  Groups in LINQ have a heirarchical shape.  Groups in SQL have a row/column shape (grouped keys + aggregates).  In order for LinqToSql to fill its hierarchy from row/column results, it must query the child nodes seperately using the group's keys.  It only does this if the children are used outside of an aggregate.

Answer (score 4):

Second answer, now I've reread the original question.

Are you sure the SQL you've shown is actually correct? It won't give the top 5 groups within each theme - it'll match each theme just against the top 5 groups *overall*.

In short, I suspect you'll get your original SQL if you use:

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes 
join g in dc.Groups.OrderBy(z => z.TotalMembers).Take(5)
  on t.K equals g.ThemeK into groups 
select new { t.Name, Groups = groups };
```

But I don't think that's what you actually want...

Answer (score 2):

Just bracket your query expression and call Take on it:

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes 
join g in dc.Groups on t.K equals g.ThemeK into groups 
select new { t.Name, Groups = 
       (from z in groups orderby z.TotalMembers select z.Name).Take(5) };
```

In fact, the query expression isn't really making things any simpler for you - you might as well call OrderBy directly:

```
var q = from t in dc.Themes 
join g in dc.Groups on t.K equals g.ThemeK into groups 
select new { t.Name, Groups = groups.OrderBy(z => z.TotalMembers).Take(5) };
```